# Session data with concurrent users in the same web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple ASP.NET 4 application with a few pages with a forms on them where the user can insert some values.
At the bottom of each page there is a button that saves these values and redirect the user to the second page, where he can insert other values, and so on, until he reach the last 4th pages.

I'm using the `Session["MyObject"]` to save these values from one page to the others.

How can I be secure that, in case my application has 2 (or more) concurrent users, each user can use the correct session object?

I mean, can a second user catch the first user's session, intead of the his?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No In session object another user cannot have any access of first user because session object created across the user mean one object for one user

Comment: You want to share MyObject to all users? You can use Application["MyObject"].

Answer (score 2):

Sessions are use specific. It is not possible to get an other users session (exception can be session highjacking by hackers).

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not wrong, the ASP .NET session is related with a unique user in a period of time, so, you'll have different sessions for each concurrent users that are filling your form.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to worry about it. Asp.Net `Session` will be always unique for two different users.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)

> ASP.NET session state identifies requests from the same browser during a limited time window as a session, and provides a way to persist variable values for the duration of that session.

Read more about

- [How to: Save Values in Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ad7zeeb.aspx)
- [How to: Read Values from Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03sekbw5.aspx)

Comment: So I can use Session without fear ;-)
Thank you all.

Comment: We will say "You'r Welcome" once you start accepting answers :). Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)